# Postgres Crosstab query with CTE (with clause)

Tags: postgresql, pivot, common-table-expression, crosstab

Recently started working on Postgres and need to pivot data.
I wrote the following query:

```
select * 
from crosstab (
$$  
    with tmp_kv as (
        select distinct pat_id  
            ,col.name as key, replace(replace(replace(value, '[',''), ']', ''),'"','') as value
        from (
            select p.Id as pat_id, nullif(kv.key,'undefined')::int as key, trim(kv.value::text,'"') as value
            from pat_table p 
            left join e_table e on e.pat_id = p.id and e.id is null
            ,jsonb_each_text(p.data) as kv
        ) t 
        left join lateral (
            select name::text as name from public.config_fields fld 
            where id = t.key 
        ) col on true
    )
    select pat_id, key, value 
    from tmp_kv 
    where nullif(trim(key),'') is not null
    order by pat_id, key 
$$,$$
    select distinct key from tmp_kv -- (Get error "relation "tmp_kv" does not exist" )
    where nullif(trim(key),'') is not null
    order by 1  
$$
) as (
    pat_id bigint
    ...
    ...
);
```

Query works if I take the `WITH` clause out into temporary table. But will be deploying it to production with read replicas, so need it to be working with a CTE. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

The two queries passed as *strings* to the `crosstab()` function are separate queries.
A CTE can only be attached to a single query.
What you ask for is **strictly impossible**.

Since you have to spell out the (static) return type for `crosstab()` anyway, and the result of the query in the 2nd parameter has to match that, it's pointless to use a query with a dynamic result as 2nd parameter to begin with.

Comment: Hi Erwin Thanks for taking time to reply, really appreciate it.
the crosstab() syntax allows two queries, the second query is category values that needs to be pivoted. So as I mentioned the query works outside without WITH clause. 

As far as referencing CTE multiple times in the query, that is also allowed (works) in Postgres.

Comment: @EsKay in the same query, yes. But `crosstab()` executes the two passed query strings *separately*, like I tried to convey in my answer.